# Importing data from CSV using loadDate liquibase. Unknown columns creating an error

Tags: java, database, csv, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Let's say I have data.csv file with some data.

```
name, lastName, something, somethingElse

John, Doe     , drinking , eating
```

I'm creating a table

```
 <changeSet id="1" author="me">
        <createTable tableName="myTable">
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="lastName" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="something" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="somethingElse" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

I want to insert my data from data.csv

```
<changeSet  author="me"  id="2" runAlways="true">
        <loadUpdateData  encoding="UTF-8"
                         file="db/data.csv"
                         schemaName="liq"
                         separator=","
                         tableName="myTable">
           <column name="name" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="lastName" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="something" type="varchar(255)"/>
            <column name="somethingElse" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </loadUpdateData>
    </changeSet>
```

This piece of code works fine. In my situation, separator is ",".
I want to figure out different scenerio.

I get data2.csv file with unfinished (unnamed) columns. It was created for future inserts.
It looks like below:

```
name, lastName, something, somethingElse,,,,

John, Doe     , drinking , eating       ,,,,
```

So I have some extra comas which are separating non existing(yet) columns.
Is that possible to configure liquibase to skip or to do not read those specific comas? In current situation I will get

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Unreferenced unnamed column is not supported
```

I have hundreds of rows and all of them contain comas at the end so removing them manually is pointless and not allowed in my situation.

Summing up I want to create table with only existing columns and insert data from
csv file. This file has extra comas at the end of each row, unfortunately
in same time comas are my columns separator. I checked list of properties and I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get Liquibase to ignore the extra commas.  However, if you used a text editor with find/replace capabilities, you could do a search and replace for the number of commas that occur at the end of the lines and replace with a single comma. ie Find: ,,,, Replace: ,  If you were able to resolve it another way, please let us know!